# Can't download Android Studio Sdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

i am trying to download this **android studio sdk** tools last 3 days and i am so tired..  I already download **java jdk** tools, i searched too much forums and *non of them* worked for me. Can you guys share with me your C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk . ***I really need help guys***.

**For First Image:**

Link 1 = https://ibb.co/hYupDJ

```
Link 2 = www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500812603287

Link 3 = cdn.pbrd.co/images/HnWPaVK.jpg
```

Link 4 = https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10212223963782851&set=a.10212223964422867.1073741827.1490122680&type=3&theater

***When starting the Android Studio, needs to download sdk tools, but doesn't download because too slow and hours later shown error***

**For Second Image:**

Link 1 = https://ibb.co/jVkRSd

```
Link 2 = www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500812605539
```

Link 3 = https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10212223975023132&set=a.10212223964422867.1073741827.1490122680&type=3&theater

***I get an error when this is done, and starting over again... Endless loop***

**For Third Image:**

Link 1 = https://ibb.co/btZgtJ
Link 2 = https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500812606153
Link 3 = https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10212223980583271&set=a.10212223964422867.1073741827.1490122680&type=3&theater

For example i tried this: **Force or unforce HTTPS** (there is an option for this under Settings), and see if this improves the quality of your connection.
Tried install Java jdk, Android Studio and  Android Studio Sdk things on different pc. Noting changed....

Comment: Please use text rather than images. Also the only relevant information is the exact error not your normal download speed or what the download screen looks like

Comment: I fixed, pls try to help me

Comment: Unable to view images, getting a 403 error. Please edit question with country, any VPN if you are using it, or if you are using a school or business network. As written there isn't even enough information to suggest an approach. Also list *what* you've tried if you've tried different things.

Comment: I added more links here

Answer (score 0):

Guys i finally **solved**. When ***Morrison Chang*** said to me "Unable to view images, getting a 403 error. Please edit question with country, any **VPN** if you are using it" i realised, i never try to install Android Studio Sdk with VPN. And i download a Vpn and tried the install sdk and worked. My download speed were 1mbps in 1 sec. Thanks Morrison Chang, really, i were crazy, I have done nothing but deal with this problem.